Are there any words in which *u is reconstructed for Late Proto-Slavic, but we aren't sure which diphthong that *u came from in Early Proto-Slavic?
I know that Late Proto-Slavic *u in words such as *umъ or *uxo or in toponyms such as Ptuj (from ancient name Poetovium) comes from Early Proto-Slavic diphthongs. So, I am interested, are there any words which contained *u in Late Proto-Slavic, but we aren't sure which Early Proto-Slavic diphthong that *u came from?
